# jQuery closure & object property access

Tags: jquery, closures

Can anyone tell me how to get access to variable "a" here:

```
var test = {
   a: 3,
   init: function() {
       $("body").click(function() {
          alert(a);
       });
   }
};

test.init();
```

This doesn't work either: alert(this.a);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I prefer this:  It's **self** setting and initializing:

```
function createX() {
    var self = {
        init: function() {
            $("body").click(this.doit);
        },

        doit: function(data, b) {
            alert(self.testing());
        },

        testing: function() {
            return 4;
        }
    }
    self.init();
    return self;
}


$(function() {
    createX();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to the object:

```
test.a
```

Comment: That couples the code to the fact that the overall object is stored in a variable called "test".  This not a good pattern since test is external to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Add a self reference:-

```
var test = {
   a: 3,
   init: function() {
       var self = this
       $("body").click(function() {
          alert(self.a);
       });
   }
};
```

Comment: This usually works, but will fail if: test.init.call(otherContext)

Comment: @Machine: true but why would you want to do that? Accessing variables outside of an object may work but doing so leads to some serious spaggeti.  Such a pattern should be considered a bad smell and avoided if possible

Comment: Ok, this works:

<pre>
var test = {
    a: 3,
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("body").click(function() {
            test.doit();
        });
    },

    doit: function() {
        var self = this;
        alert(self.a);
    }
};
</pre>

but I need to reuse the doit function, so now this doesn't work:

<pre>

var test = {
    a: 3,
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("body").click(self.doit);
    },

    doit: function() {
        var self = this;
        alert(self.a);
    }

};
</pre>

as the "this" in doit refers to the $("body") obj. ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works:

```
var test = {
    a: 3,
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("body").click(function() {
            self.doit();
        });
    },

    doit: function() {
        var self = this;
        alert(self.a);
    }
};
```

but I need to reuse the doit function, so now this doesn't work:

```
var test = {
    a: 3,
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        $("body").click(self.doit);
    },

    doit: function() {
        var self = this;
        alert(self.a);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this fixes the second problem:

```
function test() {
    var self;
    return {
        init: function() {
            self = this;
            $("body").click(this.doit);
        },

        doit: function(data, b) {
            alert(self.testing());
        },

        testing: function() {
            return 4;
        }
    }
}


$(function() {
    var x = test();
    x.init();
});
```

Comment: It might be an idea for you to read the SOFAQ.  Please don't keep adding answers as if SO were a forum or NG.  Just refine your existing answer.